# Sum column by date

Tags: excel, date, sum, spreadsheet

I have a workbook with two spreadsheets. One is 'Daily Profit and Loss' and looks like this:

```
Date      |  Profit
01/01/01  |  £1
01/02/02  |  £-1
```

And another is 'Weekly Profit and Loss'

```
Week Beginning | Profit
...
```

How can I get the sum profit per week in the 'Weekly Profit and Loss' spreadsheet?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way would be to add a another column and use the WeekNum function to determine the week of the year.

You could then use a pivot table to sum profit per week.